# JDBC (Derby) INSERT query fails with SQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: java, jdbc, derby

My INSERT query keeps failing with a SQLSyntaxErrorException. I tried to check the structure of my table to see if there's a wrong data type but I keep getting this message.
Please help me identify what's causing this error. I'm stuck. I'm not sure if my quoting of components is correct.

[image]

My .grab file details below
[image]

```
        String completeBirthday = getCompleteBirthdayFromComboBoxes(); 
        String employmentStatus = getStringValue_Of_EmploymentStatus_Selected();

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        Statement stat = con.createStatement();

        String InsertQuery = "INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(EMPLOYEE_ID,EMP_LASTNAME,EMP_FIRSTNAME,EMP_MIDDLENAME,ADDRESS,POSITION,GENDER,BIRTHMONTH,BIRTHDAY,BIRTHYEAR,EMAIL,YEARSOFEXPERIENCE,BASICSALARY,EMPLOYMENTSTATUS)"
                + "VALUES "
                + "(' "+AddEmployee_EmployeeID_TxtField.getText()+" ',' "
                + " "+AddEmployee_LastName_TxtField.getText()+" ',' "
                + " "+AddEmployee_FirstName_TxtField.getText()+" ',' "
                + " "+AddEmployee_MiddleName_TxtField.getText()+" ',' "
                + " "+AddEmployee_Address_TxtField.getText()+" ',' "
                + " "+AddEmployee_Position_TxtField.getText()+" ',' "
                + " "+AddEmployee_Gender_ComboBox.getSelectedItem()+" ',' "
                + " "+AddEmployee_BirthdayMonth_ComboBox.getSelectedItem()+" ',' "
                + " "+AddEmployee_BirthdayDay_ComboBox.getSelectedItem()+" ',' "
                + " "+AddEmployee_BirthdayYear_ComboBox.getSelectedItem()+" ',' "
                + " "+AddEmployee_Email_TxtField.getText()+" ',' "
                + " "+AddEmployee_YearsOfExperience_TxtField.getText()+" ',' "
                + " "+AddEmployee_BasicSalary_TxtField.getText()+" ',' "
                + " "+employmentStatus+" "
                + " ')"
                ;


        stat.execute(InsertQuery); //execute() will run the insert query above.
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Insert Success!");
```

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I also added a parse to convert the returned value by getText() on Basic Salary and Years Of Experience. 
int yrsOfExp = Integer.parseInt(AddEmployee_YearsOfExperience_TxtField.getText());
            int basicSalary = Integer.parseInt(AddEmployee_BasicSalary_TxtField.getText());

Comment: You should be using a `PreparedStatement` and query parameters (`.setInt`, `.setString`, etc.).

Comment: @GordThompson, thank you very much for the advice. I did some research and followed the instructions on a website(http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-mysql-insert-example-preparedstatement) about PreparedStatement and fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comment to the question, you really should be using a `PreparedStatement` to perform a *parameterized query*, along these lines:

```java
String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(EMPLOYEE_ID,EMP_LASTNAME,EMP_FIRSTNAME,EMP_MIDDLENAME,ADDRESS,POSITION,GENDER,BIRTHMONTH,BIRTHDAY,BIRTHYEAR,EMAIL,YEARSOFEXPERIENCE,BASICSALARY,EMPLOYMENTSTATUS)"
        + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement stat = con.prepareStatement(insertQuery);
stat.setString(1, AddEmployee_EmployeeID_TxtField.getText());
stat.setString(2, AddEmployee_LastName_TxtField.getText());
stat.setString(3, AddEmployee_FirstName_TxtField.getText());
stat.setString(4, AddEmployee_MiddleName_TxtField.getText());
stat.setString(5, AddEmployee_Address_TxtField.getText());
stat.setString(6, AddEmployee_Position_TxtField.getText());
stat.setString(7, AddEmployee_Gender_ComboBox.getSelectedItem());
stat.setString(8, AddEmployee_BirthdayMonth_ComboBox.getSelectedItem());
stat.setString(9, AddEmployee_BirthdayDay_ComboBox.getSelectedItem());
stat.setString(10, AddEmployee_BirthdayYear_ComboBox.getSelectedItem());
stat.setString(11, AddEmployee_Email_TxtField.getText());
stat.setInt(12, Integer.valueOf(AddEmployee_YearsOfExperience_TxtField.getText()));
stat.setInt(13, Integer.valueOf(AddEmployee_BasicSalary_TxtField.getText()));
stat.setString(14, employmentStatus);
stat.executeUpdate();
```

This approach avoids the inconvenience of having to worry about quoting string values, and prevents problems with SQL injection (e.g., so your code won't blow up when LastName is "O'Brian")

Comment: thanks again. Using prepared statements will definitely help me in future coding with DB and Java. It made everything much easier instead of quoting which is painful especially with typos.

Answer (score 1):

Try insert the number fields without surround it with ' character

Like this:

```
AddEmployee_BirthdayYear_ComboBox.getSelectedItem()+" ',' " + " 
"+AddEmployee_Email_TxtField.getText()+" '," + "
"+AddEmployee_YearsOfExperience_TxtField.getText()+" , " + " 
"+AddEmployee_BasicSalary_TxtField.getText()+" ,'
```